# Div height 100% of content

Tags: html, css, height

I have an easy question for CSS guru that is ruining my weekend.
Basically I have a div with an image on the left and some text on the right.
I need that the box height is the same of the content text so for example in the image below the last line is outside the box while I need that the box is height like the content.

I cannot use fixed height due to the text can change inside the box, I need only a min-height already defined.

Some guru can help me?

```
<a href="#" class="myClass">
    <div class="postImageUrl" style="overflow:hidden; z-index: 10; max-width: 100%;">
        <div class="imgUrl" style="background-image:url(http://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/17231820/Lorem-Ipsum.jpg);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centered-text-area clearfix">
        <div class="centered-text">
            <div class="myClass-content">
                <div class="ctaText" style="float:left;">
                    UpNeXt
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div class="postTitle" style="float:left;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And this is the <style>

```
.myClass 
, .myClass .postImageUrl 
, .myClass .imgUrl 
, .myClass .centered-text-area {
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.myClass
, .myClass:hover
, .myClass:visited
, .myClass:active {
    border:0!important;
}
.myClass {
    display: block;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
    webkit-transition: background-color 250ms;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
    webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}
.myClass:active
, .myClass:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 250ms;
    webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.myClass .postImageUrl
, .myClass .imgUrl {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.myClass .postImageUrl {
    width: 30%;
}
.myClass .imgUrl {
    width: 100%;
}
.myClass .centered-text-area {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
.myClass .centered-text {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.myClass .myClass-content {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 74px 0 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.myClass .ctaText {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #fff;
    color: #34495E;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .125em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.myClass .postTitle {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.myClass .ctaButton {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.myClass:hover .imgUrl {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.myClass .imgUrl {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

You can find the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/L26s1vc5/

This is what I see now
[image]

While this is what I expect to have:
[image]

The min-height is 100px.
I already tested with height:100%, overflow-y:auto, height:auto without success :(

Thanks for your help, Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues causing your problem.  You have a clearing issue and an absolute positioning issue.  Inside of `.myClass` you have two floated divs.  That alone would cause the issue you are having.  You've even attempted to fix it in two places.  You added a class of `clearfix` in one place (which would only work if you had a css rule to match).  You also have an empty div with an inline styling of `clear: both;`, though for that to work you would need to have it as the third div in your link.

Still, even if either of the above were working properly the issue wouldn't have been fixed.  This is because of your absolute positioning on `.centered-text`.  When you absolutely position something you take it out of the flow of your document.  This means that it's parent has no idea the size of what's inside of it.  All of your sizing was coming from your liberal use of `min-height: 100px`.  If you remove the absolute positioning on `.centered-text` and use the clearfix properly then your code works just fine.

```css
.myClass,
.myClass .postImageUrl,
.myClass .imgUrl,
.myClass .centered-text-area {
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.myClass,
.myClass:hover,
.myClass:visited,
.myClass:active {
  border: 0!important;
}
.myClass {
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 250ms;
  webkit-transition: background-color 250ms;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
  webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
}
.myClass:active,
.myClass:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
  webkit-transition: opacity 250ms;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.myClass .postImageUrl,
.myClass .imgUrl {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass .postImageUrl {
  width: 30%;
}
.myClass .imgUrl {
  width: 100%;
}
.myClass .centered-text-area {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
.myClass .centered-text {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100px;
  /* Removed absolute positioning*/
}
.myClass .myClass-content {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 74px 0 18px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.myClass .ctaText {
  border-bottom: 0 solid #fff;
  color: #34495E;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: .125em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.myClass .postTitle {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass .ctaButton {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.myClass:hover .imgUrl {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.myClass .imgUrl {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* Added clearfix class here so that it can work properly*/
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myClass clearfix"><<!-- moved clearfix here so it can take effect for the necessary area -->>
  <div class="postImageUrl" style="overflow:hidden; z-index: 10; max-width: 100%;">
    <div class="imgUrl" style="background-image:url(http://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/17231820/Lorem-Ipsum.jpg);">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="centered-text-area">
    <div class="centered-text">
      <div class="myClass-content">
        <div class="ctaText" style="float:left;">
          UpNeXt
        </div>
        <div class="postTitle" style="float:left;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
          dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

All I did remove said absolute positioning (it wasn't doing anything that I could tell), moved your clearfix to the proper place, removed your extra div (also a clearfix attempt) and added a clearfix class to the end of your css.

It looks like you've tried to do a lot of things to make this code work.  You may want to go through and see what's doing what, a lot of it looks like it's not doing anything at all.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much! Now works well but there is a way to size also the image?

Comment: DSMann8 are you a freelancer? If yes can I have your email? Could be that I need your help in future project and your response has been very detailed. I solved similar problems in other 5 boxes by myself thanks to your explaination :)

Comment: No, I'm not a freelancer.  I just a student who has researched this stuff way to much.  For your image, it's really hard to match the height of a sibling.  This is because unless the parent has a set height (percentages are really confusing here) you can't tell a child to match the height of the parent.  And there is no way to tell a sibling to match the height of another sibling.

Comment: You could change your css to use either flexbox or css tables in order to get your image to match your content.  I'll put up a codepen.

Comment: Here's the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vORGRa).  I went with css tables since you were already using them.  Mainly I just changed `.myClass` to `display: table` and took out the floats from `.postImageUrl` and `.centered-text-area` changing them to `display: table-cell`.  It works well enough, though you might need to change some of your padding to make it look the way you want it to.

Comment: OK thanks for all DSMann8. My email is alessio.ragni@gmail.com see you soon and thanks at all the replies :)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ojoevj1k/

The fiddle has the solution done via jQuery using the .height() call and JavaScript using the setInterval call.  Every 50 milliseconds, the function will check to see if the image height is the same height as the container with the text.  If they are not equal in pixel height, CSS is applied directly to make them equal.

Since this is dynamic, I did not have to change any of your CSS.

```
var makeSameHeight = setInterval( function() {
    var currentTextHeight = $('div.myClass-content').height() + "px";
    var imgDivHeight = $('div.imgUrl').height() + "px";
    if (currentTextHeight === imgDivHeight)
    {
        var doNothing = "";
    } else {
        $('div.imgUrl, div.postImageUrl, a.myClass').css("height", currentTextHeight);
    }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use only CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Only add **overflow:hidden;**

```
.myClass .myClass-content {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 74px 0 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If isn't set **height:XXpx;** the container will fit to the content.